# don´t redirect to a view and I want to show the current users' list

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have one boostrap modal on a form. When I save the data and pass the success validation.

It has me redirect a the view index, but I get the status code 302, and not redirect me well

```
public function postCreate()
    {
        //validamos reglas inputs
        $rules = array(
          'inputuser' => 'required|max:10',
          'inputpassword' => 'required|min:8',
          'inputpassword1' => 'required|min:8',
          'inputemail' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'
        );

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        //Si no pasa la validacion
        if($validation->fails())
        {
            //Obtenemos los mensajes de error de la validation
            $messages = $validation->messages();
            //Redireccionamos a nuestro formulario de atras con los errores de la validación

            if(Request::ajax())
            {
                return Response::json(array('errors' => $messages));
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
            }

        }
        //Si todo ha ido bien guardamos
        $password = Input::get('inputpassword');
        $user = new User;
        $user->username = Input::get('inputuser');
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->email = Input::get('inputemail'); 
        $user->admin = (Input::get('es_admin') == '1') ? 1 : 0;

        //guardamos
        $user->save();

        //redirigimos a usuarios

        return Redirect::to('showuser')->with('status','ok_create');
```

my redirect goes to the route of the controller

```
 return Redirect::to('showuser')->with('status','ok_create');
```

routes

```
//Rutas del sistema
Route::Controller('users','UsersController');
Route::get('showuser','UsersController@getIndex');
```

the method getIndex

```
class UsersController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth'); //bloqueo de acceso
    }

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $my_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $is_admin = Auth::user()->admin;
        //control permissions only access administrator
        if($is_admin==1)
        {
            $users = User::where('admin', '<>', '1')->where('id', '<>', $my_id)->get();
            return View::make('admin/users.index')->with('users',$users);
        }
        else
        {
            return View::make('errors.access_denied');
        }
    }
```

if status ok_create, show me in my view the user has created and close window modal.

```
 @if(!empty($status) && $status == 'ok_create')
    <script>
        $('#box-modal').on('shown', function () {
      alert('hola');
  $(this).modal('hide');
    </script>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> El usuario {{ $user->username }} fue creado con exito 
    </div>

    @endif
    <form role='form' class='form-horizontal' method='post'>
        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->admin) 
        <a id="link-modal" class='btn btn-primary pull-right' data-toggle='modal' data-target="#box-modal"><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Alta usuario</a>
        @endif
        <h2>Listado de usuarios</h2>
        @if($users && !$users->isEmpty())
        <table class='table table-striped'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Seleccionar</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Nombre de usuario</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Administrador</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' name='rusuario[]' value='{{ $user->id }}' id='{{ $user->id }}' /></td>
                    <td class='text-center'>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                    <td class='text-center'>{{ $user->username }} </td>
                    <td class='text-center'>{{ $user->email }} </td>
                    <td class='text-center'>@if ($user->admin == 1) SI @else NO @endif</td>
                    @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->admin)
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i>Modificar</a></td>
                    @endif
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

but don´t work, which is the problem?

I want to show the user´s list and close modal, I get the response but dont work
[image]

When I press the event save of my form. I have close window modal and show user list

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the error you are seeing when you're supposed to get redirected? Have you checked your logs?

Comment: I haven´t any log error

Comment: Are you using ajax to post?